# Embed an external Android application into a view/layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-view

Is it possible to embed an external Android application's main activity into one of my own application's views or layouts ?

I know how to launch another app via explicit intent, but then it takes up the whole screen. What I want is to be able to place the launched application into my app's layout along with my other widgets:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to embed an external Android application's main activity into one of my own application's views or layouts ?

Not at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you share resources on why this is not possible ? Also, is there any methods for sharing the screen between two apps ? ( I've seen [Cornerstone](http://www.onskreen.com/cornerstone) in action, and I'm wondering how they did it... )

Comment: @M4XMX: " Could you share resources on why this is not possible ?" -- not really. In general, it's for security reasons. Having arbitrary third-party code run in your process is risky, and that third-party code wouldn't work anyway (as it would not have access to its own files, its own permissions, etc.). "I've seen Cornerstone in action, and I'm wondering how they did it..." -- it's a custom ROM, near as I can tell. At the OS level, the OS can arrange to show multiple windows at once, with sufficient changes to the OS (see Samsung, LG, etc.). You want this at the *app* level.